# Is there a substitute for dashi?

Tags: substitutions, asian-cuisine, vegetarian, japanese-cuisine, dashi

I adore Japanese cooking, but when cooking for vegetarians, I don't want to use dashi (bonito) stock. However, if I just omit it, the result doesn't taste authentic.

Anyone have a substitute?

Comment: Personally, I find that Japanese (and Thai) cuisine is so commonly dependent on fish stocks, sauces, etc.  That I avoid the entire cuisine, hard to replicate the tastes without such major ingredients and without them, why bother.

Comment: Well, I'd like to try, at least. I lived in Japan for two years and I'm not going to just give up just because it doesn't taste exact. That said, I would like to make vegetarian Japanese food that tastes as authentic as possible.

Answer (score 4):

*Dashi* (だし) is a class of stocks, and while *katsuodashi* (かつおだし) made with bonito flakes is the most common type, there are plenty of alternatives.

The most common purely vegetarian one in Japan is *kombudashi* (昆布だし, こんぶだし) made from kelp.  You can try to make your own, but well-stocked Japanese grocers will have powdered instant versions of this in stock.  Here's one from [Ajinomoto](https://www.ajinomoto.co.jp/products/detail/?ProductName=hondashi_4):

[image]

Note the green packaging to differentiate it from the red/pink *katsuo* versions.  We use *kombudashi* often at home, and in miso soup etc the taste is not noticeably different from *katsuodashi*, although it does lack the strong "fishy" notes.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard of the eastern fish sauces being substituted with a mix of a little light soy sauce, and a couple of fermented bean products, yellow bean sauce and fermented tofu, blended.

If you combine the fermented products with a kombu stock (as suggested by Elendil), you might get a closer variant.  Remains to be seen how effective it would be.

Comment: Fermented tofu or yellow bean sauce are not used in Japanese cooking.